# How do i stop the label interaction in my force layout D3?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a force directed graph created in D3. It has the ability to hover over any node and it becomes highlighted.
But it also becomes highlighted when i hover over the nodes label.
What i am after is a way to still show the label for the node but i want to stop all interaction with the labels text.

The reason for this is the label is quite long and sometimes goes over other nodes but i am unable to select that node as the label is in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable pointer events for the text with the following CSS:

```
text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: perfect. Seen you answer a lot on D3 here and you've helped me a lot previously. Appreciate it, thank you.